# How to get twitter profile image from profile id

Tags: scala, twitter

How to get the most recent twitter profile image from profile id.

now i can get the profile image from static url that i saved on my db

```
href="http://www.twitter.com/{{ tweet.user.screen_name }}"
```

tweet.user.screen_name is a path of profile image when i saved the data on db.

I need a path like this: https://twitter/FunctionThatReturnThePathOfActualProfileImage/userid

have you got any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter REST API method you are looking for is called GET users/show [1]. An example request that uses the profile id would look like this:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=795649
```

The JSON response has two keys, *profile_image_url* and *profile_image_url_https*, that should contain the information you are looking for. Please note that authentication of your application via OAuth is required to make this API call.

[1] https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show